# ColorFunctionScaling example from Mathematica help fails - why?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, plot

There is an example in the [Mathematica 7 help for Plot > Options > ColorFunctionScaling](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v7/ref/Plot.html#38928736).

```
Table[Plot[Sin[4 Pi x], {x, 0, 1/2}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[x]], 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> cf], {cf, {False, True}}]
```

[image]

When I evaluate it myself on **Mathematica 7**, both output plots look like the one on the *left*.

However, if I evaluate this, I get the plot on the *right*, as shown above:

```
Plot[Sin[4 Pi x], {x, 0, 1/2}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[x]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> True]
```

Why might the example as given fail?

---

Alexey and Simon demonstrated that this is not the result of HoldAll, as I presumed before.

**The existence of the example leads me to suspect it once worked, and the information that it works on version 8 tells me that the behavior has changed.  What precisely has changed?**

Comment: Since this behaviour does not occur in the current v8, I changed the link to point to the legacy v7 documentation. (I hope that's ok!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug in fact *is* related to the HoldAll attribute, but I was fooled by [this auto-load issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649379/why-do-i-have-to-evaluate-this-twice) into thinking it was not.  This can be seen by executing this:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}];

Unprotect[Plot]
ClearAttributes[Plot, HoldAll]

Table[Plot[Sin[4 Pi x], {x, 0, 1/2}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[x]], 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> cf], {cf, {False, True}}]
```

The first `Plot` is needed to activate the package load.

One can therefore get the correct behavior by wrapping `ColorFunctionScaling -> ...` in `Evaluate`:

```
Table[Plot[Sin[4 Pi x], {x, 0, 1/2}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[x]], 
  Evaluate[ColorFunctionScaling -> cf]], {cf, {False, True}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Interestingly, which package is loaded and what is the mechanism for loading the package? `Definition[Plot]` does not give the answer.

Comment: @Alexey, did you see [the question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649379/)?  Using Plot the first time loads some .mx file that resets its attributes, so if you try the code above in a fresh kernel, **without** the first `Plot` line, `Plot` has attribute `HoldAll` again when the plots are created.

Comment: I did and in that case the mechanism can be found by looking at the definition for `LogLinearPlot`: `Unprotect[LogLinearPlot]; ClearAttributes[LogLinearPlot,ReadProtected]; Definition[LogLinearPlot]` explains what happens. In the case of `Plot` it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is really interesting. The mentioned method of supplying option values to built-in functions is widely used in the Documentation. The fact that it fails only for `ColorFunctionScaling` looks like a bug. And information that in v.8 this problem does not exist confirms that this is a bug in v.7.

In any way consider the following:

```
In[1]:= SetAttributes[f, HoldAll]
f[__, OptionsPattern[ColorFunctionScaling -> False]] := 
 OptionValue[ColorFunctionScaling]
Table[f[Sin[4 Pi x], {x, 0, 1/2}, 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> cf], {cf, {False, True}}]


Out[3]= {False, True}
```

You can see that `HoldAll` attribute in really does not prevent substituting of `cf`.

In this way, it is really interesting what was the cause of described buggy behavior of `Plot` with `Table` in v.7?

Comment: Alexey, I missed this reply.  Let me think about that! +1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  `HoldAll` does prevent the substitution all right. What you observed is due to the `Block`-like (dynamic) scoping mechanism used by `Table`, plus the magic used in `OptionValue`, which uses the run-time value for `cf`. You can use `Trace` to see that `OptionValue` expands into `OptionValue[ColorFunctionScaling->False,{ColorFunctionScaling->cf},ColorFunctionScaling]`, and then it is this evaluation where the value for the `cf` is being substituted.  Older `OptionQ` - based way of option checks was much more direct and easier to understand, and did not involve any magic.

Comment: @Leonid I did not see this until now (I believe only the first @person gets notified).  Would you please post this as an answer, with more detail?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I would prefer to not post this as an answer since my comment is tangential to the question being asked, but is a comment to @Alexey's observation. Also, I don't know how to explain it better. @Alexey noted that `HoldAll` for `f` did not prevent the substitution of `cf` by its value, and I noted that that substitution was happening not when `f[args]` was evaluated (l.h.s), but when `OptionValue` on the r.h.s of the definition for `f` was evaluated. So, my point was that it was a consequence of `OptionValue`'s evaluation and had nothing to do with the `HoldAll` attribute of `f`.

Answer (score 1):

The evaluation order seems slightly out. It works if you force `cf` to be substituted in before the `Plot` command is looked at. To do this we use the `With[{x=x},...]` construct:

```
Table[With[{cf = cf}, 
  Plot[Sin[4 Pi x], {x, 0, 1/2}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[x]], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> cf]], {cf, {False, True}}]
```

[image: plot]

It's strange that you don't need such a kludge in Mathematica version 8.

It's even stranger that the Mathematica 7 documentation has an example where the pre-evaluated graphics does not match what is produced by that version. (Nice find, btw)

Comment: Beat me to it! I suspect this was a bug with the variable localization of `cf` inside `Plot`/`Table`, and apparently fixed in 8.0, as you noted.

Comment: What else does this effect?  I thought `Table` was a valid scoping construct, and that this would/should not happen.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: `Table` uses `Block`-like scoping and `Plot` is `HoldAll`, so if `Plot` doesn't evaluate the value it won't resolve to its value.

Comment: @Brett Now I see.  I should have realized this, and I am surprised I didn't have problems with this before.  I didn't even check for that as I was confident the option value was evaluated.  I blame myself for being ignorant of this, but I console myself I am not the first (re: help file).

Comment: @Brett @Mr.Wizard: I'm not sure if it's quite that simple. Other Plot options are happy to be placed into a table, e.g. `Table[Plot[Sin[4 Pi x], {x, 0, 1/2}, PlotStyle -> {tt}], {tt, {nonesense, Thin, Thick}}]`. Or do the same with the `ColorFunction` ranging over `{Hue, GrayLevel}`....

Comment: @Simon, somehow I missed this comment and Alexey's entire answer.  Thanks for pointing this out.  Perhaps it is "just" a bug after all.